# Migrate SQL Developer proxy connection to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy, migration, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm trying to migrate my oracle db connection from sql developer to IntelliJ. There is no problem with normal connections - straight forward migration.

Now there is a proxy connection in sql developer

- "**proxy connection**" in connection creation window is checked
- in "proxy connection" window the proxy type **username** is selected and the **proxyclient** is given.

So the question is - how can i migrate this one to IntelliJ? Don't even know, if this kind of connection is possible there.
I know there is a SSH/SSL tab with ssh tunnel use option and some options for proxy usage, but i don't know if this is the right place.

In SQL Developer, there is no proxy host or proxy port. Just the normal configuration (host, servicename, port, username and password) and the proxy config with client name only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SSL/SSH* tab with **Use SSH tunnel** option is what you need. Set the proxy host/port and user credentials there. In Data Source *General* tab, specify your remote database host and credentials as usual. IDE then will use the specified proxy host to connect to the remote database.

You can use *Test Connection* button on both tabs to test both the proxy connection and the database connection.

See [SSH/SSL tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#sshAndSsl) help reference for options description.

**UPD:** Ah, you mean the connection, using [proxy user for the authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/proxya.htm#JJDBC28352), not the proxy host. This is not supported, currently. We plan to add it in future version (see the [DBE-114](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-114) request which you can vote and track for progress).

Comment: So i can't just use the configuration from sql developer and have to provide more information like proxy host/port and password? I don't have to do this in sql developer, only my proxy user. I think it's more like an "connect as" connection than a real proxy usage.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Unfortunately it is not yet supported: [DBE-114](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-114)

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Is this feature will be implemented some day? Any plans there?

Comment: Oops, overlooked your link to feature request. :D

Answer (score 0):

I was looking how to do it in SQL and you have to do :

```
SQL> CONN test_user[scott]/test_user
```

[More detail](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through)

So in IntelliJ you just have to do like that :

[image]